# WordCount Exception

Tags: java, hadoop, ubuntu-14.04

I am trying to learn hadoop using Bengfort's book about it and, as you may imagine, I am having some troubles while trying to run some examples.

I saw that there is a lot of question about the exception generated by the WordCount file, but none of them helped me.

I ran the following command, but it resulted in an error

```
hadoop jar wc.jar /WordCount shakespeare.txt /wordcounts

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: /WordCount
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:205)
at org.apache.hadoop.utilRunJar.main(RunJar.java:205)
```

Could anyone help me?

Thank you.

[image: Print Error]

Comment: Hello, why did you put slash before WordCount `/WordCount`? Bengfort did not ask to do it.

Comment: I'm aware about it, Alex. But I got a even worst error when I tried to run withou it. I added a print

Comment: Can you provide details about how you built `wc.jar` file?

Comment: It is just the jar file.
It was crated using the command line:
$ jar cf wc.jar WordCount*.class

Answer (score 0):

remove slash and try again maybe :
"hadoop jar wc.jar WordCount shakespeare.txt /wordcount"
because /WordCount 
4th one paramter Class is noy found.

Comment: Actually, I need that dash. When I remove it, I got a error even worst.

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: WordCount